# How to handle vast amount of http get request in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, api

I am trying to request 1676 http get request in spring boot.

One http get request takes about 6 second.

So if I request 1676 get request it will take about 3 hours.

How can I reduce http reqeust Time??

The code below is the code that is requesting one http get reqeust.

And I'm trying to request api by using the information that is in the List which have 1676 amount of info.

```
package com.wook.controller;

import java.time.Duration;

import org.mybatis.spring.annotation.MapperScan;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import org.springframework.web.util.DefaultUriBuilderFactory;

import com.wook.model.dto.ApiKey;
import com.wook.model.dto.Item;
import com.wook.model.dto.Items;
import com.wook.model.dto.SweatherRootRes;
import com.wook.model.dto.Temperature;
import com.wook.service.GeoService;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= {"com.wook.model","com.wook.weather","com.wook.service"})
@MapperScan("com.wook.model.dao")
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner{

    private final static String BASE_URL = "http://apis.data.go.kr/1360000/VilageFcstInfoService_2.0";
    private final ApiKey APK;
    private SweatherRootRes result;
    private Temperature temp;
    
    private GeoService gs; //To get GeoService
    
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class); //로그를 찍기 위해서 사용하는 Class
    
    @Autowired
    public Application(ApiKey apk, SweatherRootRes result,Temperature temp, GeoService gs) {
        this.APK = apk;
        this.result = result;
        this.temp = temp;
        this.gs = gs;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run( String... args ) throws Exception {
        
        String serviceKey = APK.getApiKey();
        String pageNo = "1";
        String numOfRows = "290";
        String dataType = "JSON";
        String base_date = "20211110";
        String base_time = "2300";
        String nx = "55";
        String ny = "127";

        DefaultUriBuilderFactory factory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory(BASE_URL); //UriBuilder를 생성하는 옵션을 설정하는 DefaultUriBuilderFactory 인스턴스 생성
        factory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.VALUES_ONLY); //encoding 모드 설정

        HttpClient client = HttpClient.create()
                .responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60)); //http response timeout 설정을 60초로 설정함
        
        WebClient wc = WebClient.builder()
                .uriBuilderFactory(factory) //위에서 만든 uri 인코딩 설정으로 uribuilder 설정을 함
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL) //baseURI 설정하고
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(client)) //위에서 만든 타임아웃 설정을 적용시키고
                .build(); //빌드한다.
        
        
     // This part is the part that approach to a List<GeoInfo>
        
//      for(GeoInfo gi : gs.getGeoXY()) {
//      logger.info(gi.toString());
//    }
        
        Mono<SweatherRootRes> response = wc.get()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/getVilageFcst")
                        .queryParam("serviceKey", serviceKey)
                        .queryParam("numOfRows", numOfRows)
                        .queryParam("pageNo", pageNo)
                        .queryParam("dataType", dataType)
                        .queryParam("base_date", base_date)
                        .queryParam("base_time", base_time)
                        .queryParam("nx", nx) //지역정보
                        .queryParam("ny", ny) //지역정보
                        .build()) //위 쿼리들로 uri 빌드를 하고
                .retrieve() //http 요청하고
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError,
                        error -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException("API not found")))
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError,
                        error -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Server is not responding")))
                .bodyToMono(SweatherRootRes.class);//Mono로 값을 받고
        
        
        //비동기 방식으로 약간 콜백 메소드와 같은 역할을 하는것 같다.그래서  이부분은 api 연결이 성공했을때 들어오는 부분인것 같다.
        response.subscribe(res -> {
            result.setResponse(res.getResponse());
            if(result.getResponse().getBody()!= null) {
                logger.info("http request success");
                getTemp(result.getResponse().getBody().getItems());
                logger.info(temp.toString());
            }else {
                logger.error("http reqeust has failed");
            }
        });
    }
    
    public void getTemp(Items items) {
        
        int count = 0;
        for(Item item : items.getItem()) {
            if(count >= 2 ) 
                break;
            if(item.getCategory().equals("TMX")) {
                temp.setBestMax(item.getFcstValue());
                temp.setNx(item.getNx());
                temp.setNy(item.getNy());
                temp.setDate(item.getBaseDate());
                count++;
            }
            if(item.getCategory().equals("TMN")){
                temp.setBestMin(item.getFcstValue());
                count++;
            }
                
        }
        
    }
    
}
```